# Why does the pre-gen Drow Rogue have a 0 Str modifier but a Strength score of 8?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, wizards-of-the-coast, pregenerated-characters

I just began a campaign with the pre-gen characters from the WotC page, and we can't explain some stats.

One of them is this [Drow Rogue](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/171017/Pregen-Characters-Drow-Rogue-5e?site=&test_epoch=0&manufacturers_id=44&#_=_) STR modifier. As it has STR 8, it should be -1 instead of 0, and I don't understand why.

Could you shed some light on this, please? We're new at this and we'd like to grasp these kinds of details :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems to be a mistake in the file. There is nothing special going on that I can see, so the number is likely just wrong. I don't know of any rule in the game that would be able to change an attribute modifier.

Comment: There are a couple of mistakes in the files, I can't remember what else I found - but entering the base stats into an auto-calculating sheet and it gave different numbers in at least two cases, and I only did 1st, 5th and 10th levels...

Comment: Looks like WotC needs to hire some rules lawyers!

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [Erik's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129701/43856), I would like to confirm that the mistake is in the (+0) indeed. It *could* be that the mistake was at the 8 STR instead, but it follows that: 15 Charisma, 14 Dex, 13 Int, 12 Wis, 10 Con and 8 STR give you exactly the standard array. The +2 Dex, +1 Cha from Drow then puts it into 16 Dex, 16 Cha, and finally the +2 ASI from 4th level make it go up to 18 Cha.

That's to say: **The attributes are correct - the modifier is not**. As mentioned by Erik, neither Rogues, Drows or the magic items listed are able to do anything about the modifier, so it's most likely an error.

Comment: Someone [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/9euxw2/noob_question_are_they_just_choosing_to_use_a/) suggested they did it on purpose to avoid a starter character having a negative modifier. Not sure if that's true or not. Regardless, DnDBeyond doesn't seem to have an obvious way to override that modifier and I'd prefer to do it correctly anyway :)